# iRho function in package copula

Tags: correlation, copula

The `iRho` function in the package `copula` can return unexpected `NA`, like in this case

```
iRho(claytonCopula(dim=2),.9955)
```

How can I fix it? How can I recover the source code?

I expected to find a real value, instead I found a NA

Comment: It is strange, since `rho(claytonCopula(dim=2, param=999))` does not return a number very close to 1 as expected, but 0.9953108

Comment: To recover the source code: `copula::iRho()`